# When Deploying Angular 2 app to Azure

Tags: angular, azure, karma-jasmine

I am trying to deploy a simple Angular2 application which has simple karma testing. This project was downloaded from [Angular Framework](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html)

First it showed me this error

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

, then i just changed the `Virtual applications and directories` in the Application Setting to extend to `site\wwwroot\src` then it showed me this [image: error].

Comment: What angular-cli command do you use to build your angular app?

Comment: I didnot use any command. I just ensured that app is running locally. I just pushed it over to Azure.